# How to query results from another query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I am writing a Trans-SQL script against a MSSQL 2005 Server that intends to query file path of each database present. I am able to list out the database present in the system. But how do I run a separate query based on the results?

The following is the output from the list of databases using the command (`SELECT name from sys.databases`):

```
name
----
master
tempdb
model
msdb
```

Now i would like to take this database names (e.g. master, tempdb) and enter into another query namely (`exec sp_helpdb <database_name>`).

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not answering your question directly, but if you want to run a query for each db, you can use [sp_msforeachdb](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/27/60700.aspx).

```
sp_msforeachdb 'EXEC sp_helpdb [?]'
```

Otherwise, you're going to need to use the results to generate your SQL.

Comment: yours came closest to the answer! manage to find my answer through the link u gave. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can build a cursor based on that query then loop through the results, stuff them into a SQL variable, and use that variable to exec your sproc.  Unfortunately I'm not able to give you a sample right now, but that is the way I would approach it.

Comment: yeah i was thinking along using a loop, but this is not like normal scripting

Answer (score 0):

In general, the answer to your question would be "use a subquery".

But in this case, you're using a SQL Server stored procedure.  So the best approach is to write your own stored procedure to:

1)  call sp_helpdb (or select from master..sysdatabases)

2) Iterate through the results

Here's an example:

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1070/simple-script-to-backup-all-sql-server-databases/

Answer (score -1):

If i am understanding correct , you can use derived table here:-

select database.name (your query) from
(SELECT name from sys.databases) database